# Whys can't I access httprequest variable values?

Tags: node.js, azure, httprequest

I am using the body of an httprequest, like so:

```
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {
  try {

     for (var key in req.body) {
      console.log('req.body v name=' + key + ' value=' + req.body[key]);
     }
     const rbi=req.body?.iID;
     console.log({rbi});
     const rbi2=req.body['iID'];
     console.log({rbi2});
```

the first display gives:

```
req.body v name=aT value=uuid_value
req.body v name=iID value=some_text
```

the second and third:

```
{ rbi: undefined }
{ rbi2: undefined }
```

but I think they should be `some_text`. What am I missing?

Comment: what do you see when you do console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));

Comment: The variables with uuid_value and some_text.

Comment: post the json as text

Comment: `{"aT":"uuid_value","iID":"some_text"}`

Comment: what do you see when you log   console.log(rbi2);

Comment: No, it just shows it works for you. That is the point of the question, I thought it should work as you show but it doesn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not compile correctly:

[image]

Moreover, when I remove below lines:

```
const rbi=req.body?.iID;
     console.log({rbi});
```

The code works and you get `some_text` instead of `undefined`:

[image]

Check out https://onecompiler.com/nodejs/3wuknh7g3

Here is the same code in Function App:

[image]

Comment: Hi. thanks but you are missing this: `const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest`

Comment: Do you mean in azure function you are seeing this issue?

Comment: PLs check my updated response. The same thing works fine in Function App too.

Comment: You are creating a new variable, body. Mine is the body from the request.

Comment: It is the same...pls check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231195/discussion-between-singhh-msft-and-schoon).

Comment: Does this help? If yes, pls mark it as an answer to help community.